# what is the correction preposition to be used in the blank? (in/of)

Tags: prepositions

Have you read the humorous stories **_** the Panchatantra?

Comment: It is "stories **from** the Panchatantra".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing if the Panchatantra is a book or a place or a people, I'd go with 'of' although 'in' might work too. 'About' would mean the Panchatantra were the subject of the stories, not the source.

By the way, are you taking a grammar test right now? Doing homework questions? If so, I'll tell you you're not doing yourself any favors by not learning this stuff yourself.

Comment: Panchatantra is a book.

Comment: I am practising for my english exam tomorrow.

Comment: I just want to clear my doubts so that I am well prepared for my exam tomorrow :)

Comment: OK, no offense meant. If that's a book, I would say 'in' because it a part of the story of the book.